# Constructor not defined error

Tags: apex, class

Please find my below code:

```
public with sharing class IncForRep{

    public Summary[] Summaries { get; set; }

    public IncForRep()
    {    
        List<Incident__c> results = [SELECT 
        ID , Rep_Lookup_id__c , Rep_Lookup_id__r.Name , Name FROM Incident__c
        where Rep_Lookup_id__c <> null
        ];

        Summaries = new List<Summary>();
        for (List <Incident__c> ar : results) {
            Summaries.add(new Summary(ar));
        }
    }    

    public class Summary {
        public String ID{ get; private set; }
        public String INCNAME{ get; private set; }
        public String RepName{ get; private set; }
        public String RepId{get;private set;}

        public Summary(AggregateResult ar) {
            ID = (Integer) ar.get('ID');
            INCNAME= (String) ar.get('NAME');
            RepName = (String) ar.get('RepName'); 
            RepId = (String) ar.get('Rep_Lookup_id__c ');           
        }
    }
}
```

getting error:

> Compile Error: Constructor not defined: [IncForRep.Summary].(LIST) at line 14 column 27

Can someone help me here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm guessing you've adapted this code from elsewhere, as the constructor for the `Summary` class expects a parameter of type `AggregateResult`:

```
public Summary(AggregateResult ar) {
    ID = (Integer) ar.get('ID');
    // etc.
```

Aggregate results are used when you use aggregate functions in SOQL, such as `SUM()`. Your SOQL query doesn't contain any aggregate functions and so returns a list of `Incident__c` records which you're storing in the list `results`. Since you want to create summaries for each of these records you need to adapt your constructor accordingly (or even overload it, which means adding a second constructor that takes different parameters):

```
public class Summary {
        public String ID{ get; private set; }
        public String INCNAME{ get; private set; }
        public String RepName{ get; private set; }
        public String RepId{get;private set;}

        public Summary(Incident__c i) {
        ID = i.Id;
        INCNAME= i.Name;
        RepName = i.Rep_Lookup_id__r.Name;
        RepId = i.Rep_Lookup_id__c;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You are getting this error since constructor of Summary expects an AggregateResult, instead of that that you are passing an list.